# Shell : ksh script with echo command not showing anything

Tags: shell, echo, ksh

As my title implies it I guess, I'm a beginner at shell and I've got a issue I couldn't resolve.

I'm typing my script in Notepad++ and was careful with removing the CR. I execute my script in PuttY and it doesn't show anything even though it has an echo command in it. I guess the error is iun my script but I don't know where as PuttY doesn't show me any error.

The script :

```
for ((i=wc -l <ListeTableFicToLoadRetour.lst; i>=0; i-=1)) 
do 
  echo ${i} 
done
```

The wc command works alone, it shows that there are 2 lines in the file which is correct.

When I enter the script in PuttY :
devfic@psd949(DEV/DEV):/projets/dstage/d_fic/home/devfic/sh>test.ksh
devfic@psd949(DEV/DEV):/projets/dstage/d_fic/home/devfic/sh>

I'm sorry if it's a fool's mistake, i just started ksh a few days ago :/

Comment: You want the variable i to be set to the _output_ of the wc command.  Right now the variable i is being set to wc, with redirected input being ignore.  Put backticks around wc -l <ListeTableFicToLoadRetour.lst

Comment: @LewisM, better `$(...)` than backticks -- backticks don't nest well, and `$( )` is supported not just in ksh but in all POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: Backticks as in altgr+7 backticks ? I tried and it doesn't work either :(

Comment: I'd suggest running your script with logging -- for example, `ksh -x test.ksh`, so it actually shows you each line as it's executing it.

Comment: BTW, note that just running `test.ksh` **shouldn't** work unless your system is configured with `.` in `PATH` -- a practice with some major security issues. In theory, you should need to add a shebang, like `#!/usr/bin/env ksh`, as the first line of the script; make it executable with `chmod +x test.ksh`, and either qualify the path -- like `./test.ksh` to specify to the shell that it's found in the current directory -- or install the script in a location in your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc -l <ListeTableFicToLoadRetour.lst` needs to be executed:

```
for ((i=$(wc -l <ListeTableFicToLoadRetour.lst); i>=0; i-=1)) 
do 
  echo ${i} 
done
```

Comment: I tried with $(...) but doesn't work either, still no outputs :(